# A Polynomial with square values

Tags: polynomials

Can I find the number of values ​​of the variable X for which the value of the polynomial

$100X^2+160X+M$

is a perfect square, depending on M

Comment: What are your thoughts?  You might complete the square in $X$, getting (something in $X)^2$ + something else=$K^2$.  What do you know about the difference of two squares?

Comment: Yes,I can do that,but then...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(10X+8)^2=100X^2+160X+64$.
If $100X^2+160X+M=Y^2$, then $M-64=(Y+10X+8)(Y-10X-8)$, so it suffices to check the finitely many factorizations $M-64=ab$, and among these the cases with $a-b\equiv 16\pmod{20}$.